# Member Detection for private const member function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build a trait for member detector when the member is const and private. I can use the idiom DetectX from  [wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Member_Detector)

```
template<typename T>
class DetectX
{
    struct Fallback { int X; }; // add member name "X"
    struct Derived : T, Fallback { };

    template<typename U, U> struct Check;

    typedef char ArrayOfOne[1];  // typedef for an array of size one.
    typedef char ArrayOfTwo[2];  // typedef for an array of size two.

    template<typename U> 
    static ArrayOfOne & func(Check<int Fallback::*, &U::X> *);

    template<typename U> 
    static ArrayOfTwo & func(...);

  public:
    typedef DetectX type;
    enum { value = sizeof(func<Derived>(0)) == 2 };
};
```

But the idiom doesn't differentiate between private  const member function and private non-const member function.It just happens to detect both `non-const` and `const` `private` member function.

I think  the `const` information is lost when you take address of `(&U::X)` .

How do i detect a private member function and differentiate between const and non-const private member function of the same class ?

After looking at Tyker's code i could get a C++03 implementation using friend . I'm still waiting to see a solution without friend.

```
/* Start - decltype simulation in c++03 */
template <size_t>
struct TypeId;

#define REGISTER_TYPE(T, id)               \
  template <>                              \
  struct TypeId<id> {                      \
    char value[id];                        \
    typedef T type;                        \
    static char const* const name;         \
  };                                       \
  char const* const TypeId<id>::name = #T; \
  TypeId<id> type_to_id(T);

#define TYPEID_(value) TypeId<sizeof(type_to_id(value))>
#define TYPEOF(value) typename TYPEID_(value)::type
#define TYPENAME(value) TYPEID_(value)::name

REGISTER_TYPE(int, 1)
REGISTER_TYPE(unsigned int, 2)

/* End - decltype simulation - c++03 */

template <typename T>
class DetectX {
  template <typename V>
  struct Check;

  template <typename U>
  static char& func(
      Check<TYPEOF((*(const U*)0).mem())>*);  // use const U* or U*

  template <typename U>
  static short& func(...);

 public:
  typedef DetectX type;
  enum { value = sizeof(func<T>(0)) };  // returns 1 or 2
};

class bar {
 private:
  int mem() const;
  template <typename T>
  friend class DetectX;
};
/* Register class  and function signatures */

#define REGISTER_CLASS(X) \
  typedef int (X::*pf)(); \
  typedef int (X::*pfc)() const;

REGISTER_CLASS(bar)
REGISTER_TYPE(pf, 3)
REGISTER_TYPE(pfc, 4)

int main() { std::cout << DetectX<bar>::value << std::endl; }
```

Comment: Heads-up: this technique goes to great lengths to be C++03-compatible. If you don't need that, way simpler implementations exist.

Comment: This is basically ancient SFINAE magic.

Comment: This detection only check if `&T::X` exists. Not sure if we can detect type of private members though :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate an object from `std::declval<T>()`, then cast it to const, then invoke the member function. Do this in a SFINAE function. The function should have two overloading versions with different return types. Use `decltype` and `std::is_same` to check the return type in order to know if the member function is const-qualified.

Comment: `std::declval<const T/*&*/>()` wouldn't require cast.

Comment: invocation of the member function would fail, as `private`.

Answer (score 1):

it is possible with to detect const private members with the following code.

the only drawback is a friend declaration,  but i don't think it can be done without.

```
template<typename T, typename...>
using first_type = T;

class private_const_test {
    template<typename = void>
    static constexpr std::false_type has_const_test_impl(...) {
        return std::false_type();
    }

    template<typename T>
    static constexpr first_type<std::true_type, decltype(std::declval<const T>().test())> has_const_test_impl(T) {
        return std::true_type();
    }
public:
    template<typename T>
    static constexpr bool has_const_test = decltype(has_const_test_impl(std::declval<T>()))::value;
};

class public_const_test {
    template<typename = void>
    static constexpr std::false_type has_const_test_impl(...) {
        return std::false_type();
    }

    template<typename T>
    static constexpr first_type<std::true_type, decltype(std::declval<const T>().test())> has_const_test_impl(T) {
        return std::true_type();
    }
public:
    template<typename T>
    static constexpr bool has_const_test = decltype(has_const_test_impl(std::declval<T>()))::value;
};

template<typename T>
constexpr bool has_private_const_test = private_const_test::has_const_test<T> && !public_const_test::has_const_test<T>;

struct A {
    friend class private_const_test;
  private:
    void test() const {}
};

struct B {
    friend class private_const_test;
    void test() const {}
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << has_private_const_test<A> << std::endl; // true
    std::cout << has_private_const_test<B> << std::endl; // false
    std::cout << has_private_const_test<int> << std::endl; // false
}
```

Comment: If class has to have `friend`, simpler to require a public traits then.