# Member Detection for private const member function when Inherits private from the base class

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to build a trait for member detector for Distinguish between base and derived classes by the private member isA;

I can use the idiom `private_const_test` from [Member Detection for private const member function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57006183/22193627).

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename...>
using first_type = T;

class private_const_test {
    template<typename = void>
    static constexpr std::false_type has_const_test_impl(...) {
        return std::false_type();
    }
    template<typename T>
    static constexpr first_type<std::true_type, decltype(T::isA)> has_const_test_impl(T) {
        return std::true_type();
    }
public:
    template<typename T>
    static constexpr bool has_const_test = decltype(has_const_test_impl(std::declval<T>()))::value;
    // public:
    //     template <typename T>
    //     using has_DoGetDataChain_t = decltype(T::isA);

    //     template <typename T>
    //     static constexpr bool has_const_test =
    //         std::experimental::is_detected_v<has_DoGetDataChain_t, T>;

};

template<typename T>
constexpr bool has_private_const_test = private_const_test::has_const_test<T>;

class A {
private:
    friend class private_const_test;
    static constexpr bool isA = true;
};

class B : public A {
};

class C : public B {
};

class D :public C {
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << has_private_const_test<A> << std::endl; // true
    std::cout << has_private_const_test<B> << std::endl; // false
    std::cout << has_private_const_test<C> << std::endl; // false
    std::cout << has_private_const_test<D> << std::endl; // false
}
```

I expect output "true false false false" , but I get "true true true true"

Comment: THis looks more like an attept at C++98 approach converted to C++11 syntax. But how you expect this to work? All supplied classes contain `::isA` and its type is public

Answer (score 3):

The test you want to write doesn't need a private member nor does it need friend constexpr function. You can build your logic using type_traits.
I made the example a bit more interesting by saying A is NOT a baseclass of itself (default std::is_base_of_v states it is).

Example :

```
#include <type_traits>

class A {};
class B : public A {};
class C : public B {};
class D :public C {};

template<typename base_t, typename derived_t>
static constexpr bool is_base_of()
{
    return 
        !std::is_same_v<base_t, derived_t> && 
        std::is_base_of_v<base_t, derived_t>;
}

int main()
{
    // constexpr and (meta)template expressions
    // can be checked at compile time, no need
    // to use std::cout
    static_assert(!is_base_of<A, A>());
    static_assert(is_base_of<A, D>());
}
```

Comment: Learn an interesting idea， but e this is not what I'm looking for.

I may not have been clear, I would like to distinguish it by private members ::isA, not just an inherited relationship.

Comment: Ok I understand you now

Comment: However I would not know why you have to be able to inspect anything about the private section of a class from outside that class. What is your use case?

Comment: I actually need to make sure that every derived class adds `macro`, and member A is part of that `macro`. So we need to do this test

Comment: If it detects that the derived class has not written the macro, the program will crash in the compiler

Comment: But the return value in this code is not the result of prefetching, and I can't find the reason for this confusion

Comment: Then make sure you have a baseclass that has macro as a protected member and derive classes from that. And then you can use is_base_of _v checking for that baseclass. Or can macro be different types in different classes? It still seems like you are looking for a workaround instead of solving things by design. (but I could be wrong, and I still do not understand you)

Comment: Yes, you get it. but different classes introduce the same macros, and I can only do this for a few reasons.

Comment: At present, I am trying to use constraints `require` to solve this problem. It is necessary to introduce virtual functions in macro to return different types for each class. Do you think this is feasible

Answer (score 2):

Your SFINAE check relies on visbility of `A::isA`. But `class A` is a `friend` of context where we try it and  `class A` is visible in each of four classes. Making `class A` an invisible member of `class B` would do.

```
class B: private A {
};
```

would give you desired result as long as `private_const_test` is not a friend of B.

Base class can be distinguished by attempting to convert a pointer to derived class to a pointer to base one, which [`std::is_base_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) does.

Comment: Attempting to convert a pointer to drives to a pointer to base tests for an "is-a" relationship (accessible, unambiguous base) which is not what is_base_of tests (it returns true for private bases).

Comment: @JeffGarrett indeed, but detection uses same SFINAE style as OPs , but with `static_cast`.  But that's not what OP was trying to do. They were trying to detect a private member by exploiting friendship with base class. In their case "is-a" relationship between base and derived class is what messing with their idea

Comment: Friends cannot be passed and `isA` is private member, `T::isA` is invisible to `B C D` , so  `has_private_const_test<B>` should return false. I still can't understand why the declaration causes the result of returning true.

Comment: @storyteller if C is friend of of A and B and D are subclasses of A and C respectively, C is still a friend of A that is part of B, but not a friend of B while D is neither

Comment: @storyteller `T::isA` is invisible to B C D, in your example, but `B::A`, `C::A` and `D::A` is visible to anything that accesses B, C, D. Full name of inherited `isA` in `B` is `B::A::isA` and friend of `A` can access it. IF `A` is a private base of `B`, to access it you need have a friend of `B`. That's the point of inheritance access specifier - to break that chain (very rarely a useful one)

Comment: @Swift - Friday Pie Thanks ,  I might get it.

Although isA  private member of A.  But `private_const_test<B>` can access IsA through B::A::isA because of private_const_test is friend of A.

Thank you again